# How to add a SQL max(date) calculation into a SQL table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have table like...

```
Field
Id (INT)
Customer (STRING)
OrderDate (Date)
```

I want to add the MAX(OrderDate) as a field into the table, like...

```
Field
Id (INT)
Customer (STRING)
OrderDate (Date)
MaxOrderDate (Date)
```

Any suggestions on how to build a (BigQuery) SQL query to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would use a window fucntion:

```
select t.*, max(OrderDate) over () as maxOrderDate
from t;
```